# Cannot set secret in GitHub for CID/CD Azure integration?

Tags: github, web, azure-devops, blazor-webassembly, secret-key

I'm trying to build a CID/CD pipeline between a GitHub repo and a Blazor WebAssembly web app hosted in Azure but I keep getting an error when I try to create the workflow. This is the error that I receive in Visual Sudio:

[image]

I tried to run the CLI command and paste the generated secret into the second step but I receive the same error. I also tried to manually create the MUSCLEBY_FFF file and to add it manually into the repository but it also did not worked. The app is hosted and is up and running on azure and is connected in deployment center with github, but I cannot manage to set the secret and build the deployment workflow.

I'm using Visual Studio 16.10.4 with .NET CORE 5 in a hosted Blazor WebAssembly webapp.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/what-is-azure-cli). I found it easiest to use CLI on Azure Portal as all the authentication is handled at that point.
2. Execute the command prompted in the Visual Studio dialog. In your case it would be this
   [image]
3. Take a copy of the output
4. Navigate to GitHub project, [add a secret](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets#creating-encrypted-secrets-for-an-environment) where the name is *MUSCLEBY_FFFF* and the value is the output of the CLI (yes, the whole string that looks like a publish profile XML)

Thats it, if you restart Visual Studio publish process it should be able to pick up the secret.